# How to make conditional formatting work with jxls

Tags: jxls

I have created an Excel template for jxls 2.x. There is one cell I have applied conditional formatting. However the conditional formatting only works in exactly the same cell I have created, and it is not duplicated to the following rows. Any idea?

Comment: just a heads up that this has been resolved. The issues I linked to in my answer are marked as resolved on their page just so you know. Good luck ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug related to this, as well as a feature enhancement request.

Both are currently unsolved by the developers.

You can check the bug [here](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/110/conditional-formatting-rules-are-not)

The original related issue (feature enhancement) [here](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/89/conditional-formattings-are-not-copied)

Both reports I've linked contain examples and links to them.
Read the discussion there, however brief they may be.

Issues are #89 and #110 on the bitbucket report page.

In case you want conditional formatting to be applied to all values in
column A you can set it as a conditional formatting for column A in xls
template.

You should edit your question and provide examples (template/file) and/or code. We need to see what you're actually doing - it's a bit badly phrased at the moment.

Comment: just a heads up that this has been resolved. The issues I linked to in my answer are marked as resolved on their page just so you know. Good luck ^_^